# Replace house # with House No. using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find and replace the house number in the address string.
The address string is as follow

1. House No.34 Street No. 45 Defense road
2. House #334 Street # 323 Bangla 133

So, I want to find replace different variations of House number with 
a string House no.

The different variation of the house number are as follows:

1. House No.
2. Ho. No
3. H#
4. House #
5. Ho #
6. Ho no.

I have tried to use the following regular expression to achieve this but it fails for most
of the house number string variations.

```
string hno_regex =  ((i?)h.[^#]*.);
```

Can you please suggest a regular expression to find the variation of the house number string..?

Comment: I don't think that you really did use that regex. For example, you forgot the quotes around it. If you provide code, please copy and paste it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
hno_regex = @"(?i)\bH(?:o(?:use\b|\.)?)?\s*(?:#|\bno\b\.?)";
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?i)   # case-insensitive mode on
\b     # Match a word boundary (start of word)
H      # Match H
(?:    # Try to match...
 o     # an o
 (?:   # followed by...
  use  # "use"
  \b   # (end of word)
 |     # or
  \.   # a dot.
 )?    # Make that part of the match (use|.) optional
)?     # as well as the previous part (o).
\s*    # Match optional whitespace
(?:    # Try to match
 [#]   # a hash mark
|      # or
 \b    # (start of word)
 no    # "no"
 \b    # (end of word)
 \.?   # optional dot.
)      # (End of alternation)
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` in your pattern (or have one too many `(`). And it doesn't match HoNo or HNO because you have `\bno`.

Comment: sorry  i missed the quotation mark thanks alot for the help it works :-) can you plz explain it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the direct way. Just put all of the matches in a group.

regex="\bH(ouse No.|o. No|#|ouse #|o #|o no.)"

House No.
Ho. No
H#
House #
Ho #
Ho no.